# Get the key using the value in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to extract a hash selector key as a string?

For instance:

`some_hash[:foo].some_method` *=> `"foo"`*

`user[:id].key_name` *=> `"id"`*

`params[:user_id].key_to_s` *=> `"user_id"`*

Comment: You want something like `:foo.to_s`?

Comment: Why don't you call `to_s` on the key if you have the key already? Or do you have `v = some_hash[key]` and from `v` and `some_hash`, you want to get `key` back?

Comment: I don't have the key beforehand, so your second example, @mu_is_too_short

Comment: If you don't have the key (e.q. `:id`) beforehand, how can you write this part: `user[:id].key_name`?

Comment: If the values of the hashes are unique, you could use [Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert). For example: `some_hash = { foo: 3, goo: 4 }; some_hash.invert[3].to_s #=> "foo"`. That might be OK even when the values are not unique, unless in that case you want to return an array of matching keys. Alternatively, `some_hash.find { |_,v| v==3 }.first.to_s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get only the first key from the hash that matches the value in `v`:

```
some_hash.key(v).to_s
```

#### Update

For completeness, in ruby 1.8 the `key` method was called `index` so if you're still stuck in 1.8 land:

```
some_hash.index(v).to_s
```